# How to proper create Apache2 container in Docker

Tags: php, docker, apache

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && \
    rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf && \
    service apache2 restart
```

And I am running container on that images in this way:

```
sudo docker run -d --name apache2-container -e TZ=UTC -p 8080:80 -v /home/xxx/www:/var/www/html -v /home/xxx/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf my_image
```

`/home/xxx/apache2.conf` is:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

HostnameLookups Off

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

There aren't any errors during creating image or creating container, but when I try to visit `localhost:8080`, site is loading for 15 minutes without any result.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, but here is a couple of debugging questions:

- did you rebuild the image after editing your docker file?
- what the network tabs says when you do a request? (Is there any redirections)
- can you try without you htaccess config to see if this is the problem?
- what is your index.php file looks like in the base directory (var/www/html)?